# How to access a file in downloads from root?

Tags: 19.10, root

I'm a root user `sudo -i`, now i want to execute the `Downloads/my.sh` from root. how do i do that?

Comment: try: bash ~/Downloads/my.sh,   if it is under a different username Download folder, then try: bash ~username/Downloads/my.sh make sure you specify the right username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a real noob back then.

```
~/Downloads/my.sh
```

Thanks [@NiteRain](https://askubuntu.com/users/229828/niterain) for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sudo -i` starts a new shell as root.  Use `sudo su`, or `sudo -s`, which lets you switch users, so you are logged in as root.  Then, you can just enter the Downloads directory with `cd Downloads` and run your script.

Comment: ... or `sudo -s`

Answer (score 1):

First you should know there are 2 ways:

First make your file executable just right click it, under permission tab check allow executing file as program

The Graphical way

A.1) Open your file manager as root(Assuming you are using Ubuntu gnome version if not, change nautilus for your file manager)

```
$ sudo nautilus
```

A.2) With your file manager is open as root, you should navigate to the folder containing your executable file

A.3) Now you just double click it, if didn't work you right click it and then click "open with" and in the new window select "list all" and now you can search for "execute program" or something similar

The Terminal Way

B.1) You open your Terminal Window and the you type(just to be sure you are at your home directory)

```
$ sudo cd
```

B.2) Now you type this

```
$ sudo ./Downloads/my.sh
```

alternate way is

```
$ cd the/route/to/the/folder/containing/the/file
```

and now you execute

```
$ sudo ./file.sh
```

if you want to execute something as root user, not just asking for permission try this

```
$ sudo su
```

and now you locate the file and execute it

```
$ ./usr/arghadip/downloads/file.sh
```

edited it for your needs as you commented it

Comment: but i want to call it as `root /usr/arghadip/downloads/file.sh`

Comment: could use {sudo su} and then type the route with cd,

Comment: can i copy the parent dir to the root? it's a 4 GB folder containing a lot of other files. So i could execute it directly inside `root /Desktop/myfolder/myfile.sh` if it's possible write me the copy command

Comment: I edited it with your last comment's needs
and you just type cp -R /etc /home/Downloads/    <---- this will copy etc folder recursively with all the files and folders inside it to Downloads inside home

Comment: nevermind i got what i want

Answer (score 0):

- You need to use absolute path:

```
Ex:
/home/username/Download/my.sh
```

- When you write command `root -i` you are the root user. So that, If you write command `Download/my.sh` it will be take as `/root/Download/my.sh`.
- If your are simple user `Download/my.sh` is like `/home/username/Download/my.sh`.
  So, when you are the root user you need to give command form where you are (absolute path).

Comment: `Download/my.sh` will only behave like `/Download/my.sh` when the current directory is `/`. This is independent of what user account one is logged in as, and no more likely to occur when logged in as root. By simulating a full login, `sudo -i` causes the current directory to be root's home directory; but root's home directory is `/root`, not `/`.